# In a Spring Boot RestController, how to map the following Json to a Map inside a wrapper class

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

In a Spring Boot RestController, how to map the following Json to a Map inside a wrapper class. As of this code Wrapperclass is null, no mapping happening. Code works when I directly use the EnumMap in requestBody, but I need to use a Wrapper class.

Request:

```
{
    "monday": [
        {
            "name": "task1",
            "allotedTime": 15
        }
    ],
    "tuesday": [
        {
            "name": "open",
            "allotedTime": 20
        },
        {
            "name": "close",
            "allotedTime": 60
        }
    ]
}
```

RestController method:

```
 @PostMapping("/taskApi")
    public ResponseEntity<String> createTaskList(@Valid @RequestBody
                                                      WrapperClass wrapperclass
                                                      BindingResult result) {
//logic
    }
```

Wrapper class:

```
@Data
public class WrapperClass {
  
    private EnumMap<DayOfWeek, List<Task>> taskList;
}
```

Task class:

```
@Data
public class Task {

    private String name;

    @Min(value = 0, message = "Time should not be less than 0")
    private int alottedTime;

}
```

Comment: Spring uses jackson for json deserialization, and jackson requires the type of key and value for successful deserialization of `Map`, so instead of using `EnumMap` directly, consider using `Map` with `DayOfWeek` as the key type and `List<Task>` as the value type

Answer (score 0):

As your wrapper class have key as `taskList`, for Jackson to deserialize you will need to pass the request body as below

```
{
    "tasklist": {
        "monday": [
            {
                "name": "task1",
                "allotedTime": 15
            }
        ],
        "tuesday": [
            {
                "name": "open",
                "allotedTime": 20
            },
            {
                "name": "close",
                "allotedTime": 60
            }
        ]
    }
}
```